# Getting Google map to properly load before jQuery Mobile page is shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3

**Issue:**
I have a dialog page in a jQuery Mobile document which contains a small Google map to show a location. I want to load the map before loading the dialog page. As in:

```
$("#dialogPage").bind("pagebeforeshow", function() {
    initializeSmallMap();
});
```

However, Google Maps works incorrectly whenever the `div` the map is contained in is has a `display` proprety of none (see [Google Maps Display:None Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700594/google-maps-displaynone-problem)). And since this function is executed before the page is actually loaded, the containing `div` naturally has a `display` property of none.

Now, obviously, there's a simple solution to this. All I need to do is initialize the map after the page has been shown, which makes the `div` have a display property of block:

```
$("#dialogPage").bind("pageshow", function() {
    initializeSmallMap();
});
```

However, since the dialog has already been loaded, there is an annoying, noticeable flicker when the map appears.

**Question:**
How do I get rid of the described flicker?

**Possible Solutions:**

Making the `div` containing the map have a `display` property of block before the dialog is loaded. If I wasn't using jQuery Mobile, it would be simple and painless to implement this effect while still hiding the map until needed:

```css
position: absolute;
left: -10000px;
display: block;
```

However, since jQuery Mobile automatically overrides page styles, I don't know how I could get this to work.

Explicitly telling the Google Maps API the size of the `div` containing the map. I Googled this option and had no luck, but considering my terrible Googling skills, I would not be completely surprised if this was actually possible.

Others - I'm open to any ideas on how to get rid of the flicker effect. The above are just some possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#dialogPage").promise().done(function() {
   //Code to execute when map is loaded.
 });
```

You could try it out. Just hide the element with the attr() and display it with attr() when promise().done is executed :) And you should be in no use of display properties.

Ref - [Promise](http://api.jquery.com/promise/)

Comment: I'm not sure how I would use this or whether not it could work. If I put it in the `pagebeforeshow` event, there will be no queued actions on the dialog page, and would therefore execute immediately. If I put it in the `pageshow` event, the page will have already loaded, and the flicker effect would therefore be noticeable.