# Image not display correctly inside <div style="display:none;">

Tags: javascript, google-maps

In a Web Page, I'm trying to get the coords of an adress given by the user.

I'm trying to do something like: http://www.bufa.es/google-maps-latitud-longitud/

But I have a problem. The map is placed inside a div with this structure:

```
<div id="divgeolocalizacion" style="display:none;">
...
<div style="width:100%; clear:both;">
    ...
    <div style="float:left; width:57%; margin-right:3%;">
        <div id="map">
            ...
        <div>
    <div>
<div> 
<div>
```

The user has a button on the page, which executes some javascript code. This code only changes the div display style to 
"block". The problem is that the map is very very small. However, when I open developers's tools with F12, the image changes its size.

Why i'm getting this strange behaviour? Before you ask, I didn't have any "console.log()" on my javascript code.

Pd: When div's display style is initially set to "block" all works perfectly.

Comment: Instead of editing the answer into your question, it would be a big help to the community if you added the answer as an answer (I think you need to wait a day or so) and mark it as accepted. This way we (the community) know this is answered, and others know what worked for you.

Comment: I just did it. I tried to do it yesterday, but it didn't let me. However it says that I have to wait a day to accept it

Comment: Thanks. I knew there was a delay before you could accept it, I just couldn't remember how long it was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this solution by vaelico here: [Google Maps Display:None Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700594/google-maps-displaynone-problem/8595674#8595674)

To solve the problem is necessary to add this line in the javascript after changing the div's display style:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
```

Answer (score 0):

`none` and `block` are values of the `display` property, so you should have either

```
display: none;
```

or

```
display: block;
```

in your tag's `style` attribute, not the values alone.

Comment: I know that. Maybe i dind't explain well. I'm going to edit my question