# Google Maps Javascript - Resize event listener not being called

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've got a map in a hidden div that gets revealed by a button press. I was initially having issues but they were fixed by triggering a resize event. My issue now is that the map isn't centered on the position that I initialise the map with.

I want to add a map.setCenter(?) call in to the resize or bounds changed event listener but they never seem to be called. I've put alerts in each one to test but nothing happens.

EDIT: Example as requested...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Simple markers</title>
  <style>
  html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  #theButton {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 400px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: orange;
    z-index: 100;
  }
  #map {
    height: 100%;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="theButton" onclick="resizeMap();">Click Me</div>

  <div id="map"></div>

  <script>
  function initMap() {
    var myLatLng = {lat: 51.320151, lng: -0.555658};

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 4,
      center: myLatLng
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatLng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Test Location!'
    });

    var getCen = map.getCenter();

    var currentMapCenter = null;
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'resize', function () {
        currentMapCenter = map.getCenter();
        alert("Resizing");
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function () {
        if (currentMapCenter) {
        // react here
            map.setCenter(currentMapCenter);
            alert("Centering");
        }
        currentMapCenter = null;
    });
  }

  function resizeMap() {
    alert("Clicked");
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
  };
  </script>

  <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?signed_in=true&callback=initMap"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: @geocodezip I've included an edit in my original question, hopefully that helps.

Comment: Your example doesn't seem to have a hidden div.  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/e0tyabp6/)

Comment: @geocodezip It doesn't, I've provided a simplified example as it wouldn't be practical for me to post the original code. This provides a demonstration of what is happening - The resize is triggered by a JS function attached to a button. The Map appears fine but the resize listener doesn't appear to get called.

Comment: You are expecting the `google.maps.event.trigger` to change the size of the `map` div? It doesn't, it just tells the API that the size has changed so it can re-calculate based on the new size.

Comment: @geocodezip Yes, I understand that's what happens. When I reveal the containing div by changing the display attribute to something other than none, it changes the bounds of the div, therefore, I trigger a resize event so that the map is displayed, otherwise it doesn't get shown - http://stackoverflow.com/a/8595674/4512316

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested more deeply your code there is a problem with the scope of the var `map` 
change declaration in this way (in window scope outside the function initMap local scope)

```
<script> 
var map;

     function initMap() {
        var myLatLng = {lat: 51.320151, lng: -0.555658};

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 4,
          center: myLatLng
        });
     ........
      ......
```

Otherwise map is not correctly referenced in ths other function  eg:

```
function resizeMap() {
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

In this function if you don't change the var declaration map is not referenced and the nothing can be triggered

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem is that i'm not writing this for a window resize. I'm creating a hidden map in a div with display:none, so to get the map to appear when I change the div to display:block I have to trigger the map resize event. Also in the example I provided, I never get to see the alerts in the resize and bounds changed event listeners, they are never called.

Comment: I have tested deeeply your app and modified the answer. Now work

Comment: Thanks, I'll test that out as soon as I can