# How to implement toggle effect to ng-map

Tags: angularjs, ng-show, ng-hide, ng-map

I am using ngmap to my project.I need to implement initially ng-map should hide,if we click button then it will visible and again click it should hide. i did using ng-hide and ng-show method,but if we click button its getting gray color and map does not working, Can some one help me, Thanks in advance

Comment: ----------
<button ng-click="clickme()>Click me</button>
<ng-map center="12.76,76.11" ng-show="clicked"></ng-map>
JS:  $scope.clickme = function(){
   $scope.clicked = true;
  }... This is the code

Answer (score 0):

We ran into the same issue and this StackOverflow page helped us out a lot.

[Google Maps Display:None Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700594/google-maps-displaynone-problem/8595674#8595674)

We also used lazyload which worked as well.

https://ngmap.github.io/#/!map-lazy-inint.html

Hopefully this helps.