# Google Map Hide and show Map

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using angularjs and i'm using ng-if to show and remove a directive that is presenting a map from google maps, but every time i remove the directive and put it again the map doens't load and goes grey. Does anyone have any ideia or knows how i can solve this problem.

This is the accordion code:

```
<uib-accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
        <uib-accordion-group ng-repeat="mission in missions" is-open="status.open">
            <uib-accordion-heading >
                <div class="noOutline">
                    <i class="fa fa-map-o fa-2x pull-left"></i>
                    {{mission.description}}
                    {{status.open}}
                </div>
            </uib-accordion-heading>
            <missions-Map id='map' missionId='20' ng-if="status.open"></missions-Map>
        </uib-accordion-group>
    </uib-accordion>
```

This is the directive code:

```
angular.module("dronesIntershipProject").directive('missionsMap', function () {
var opened = false;
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: "<div></div>",
    replace: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        console.log(attrs.ngIf);
        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(20,20);
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
            scrollwheel: true,
            zoom: 8
        });
        var marker =  new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
            title: "My Marker"
        });
        marker.setMap(map);
        document.getElementById('map').removeAttribute("ng-if");
        console.log(element);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `ng-show` instead of `ng-if`?

The [ngIf documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) states:

> The ngIf directive **removes or recreates** a portion of the DOM tree
>   based on an {expression}. If the expression assigned to ngIf evaluates
>   to a false value then the element is removed from the DOM, otherwise a
>   clone of the element is reinserted into the DOM.

When creating the map, you attach to the `map` element, but once it is removed by `ngIf` it is simply gone. You would have to recreate the map, in order for it to show up again.

The [documentation for ngShow](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) states:

> The ngShow directive **shows or hides the given HTML element** based on
>   the expression provided to the ngShow attribute. The element is shown
>   or hidden by removing or adding the .ng-hide CSS class onto the
>   element.

By using `ng-show`, you will be able to achieve your goal, since it simply hides the element by adding a CSS class to it, instead of completely removing it from the DOM like `ng-if`.

Comment: Yes i've tried, but instead of not only showing after i close and reopen the accordion the map doesnt even load properly the first time.

Comment: Perhaps you could use the directive to apply a custom CSS class and hide it that way? I found a question in which this is done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700594/google-maps-displaynone-problem).

It looks like hiding an element using `display: none;` may be causing some issues with Google Maps, which may be part of the problem with `ngIf`.